# Ghost Margin on TemplatedView on Xamarin.Forms platform

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've got an issue i can't quite understand yet.

For some reason Padding causes the rendering of my control to behave as if i specified it as margin as well. I've added a picture to show what appears like a bug to me.

[image: Picture]

#### contents of my xaml page:

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                <ContentView Style="{StaticResource ContentViewTappableLabelInDrawer}">
                    <controls:EnhancedLabel Style="{StaticResource LabelDrawerListHeader}" Text="FILTER" />
                </ContentView>
                <controls:EnhancedSwitch Padding="{StaticResource TappableThickness}" Text="Inaktive Standorte anzeigen"
                                         Margin="0"
                                         IsToggled="{Binding Path=IsConsideringInactive, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <controls:EnhancedSwitch Padding="0" Text="Wbs Elemente anzeigen"
                                         Margin="0"
                                         IsToggled="{Binding Path=IsConsideringWbs, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <controls:EnhancedLabel Style="{StaticResource LabelDrawerListHeader}" Text="{Binding Path=IsConsideringInactive, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <controls:EnhancedLabel Style="{StaticResource LabelDrawerListHeader}" Text="{Binding Path=IsConsideringWbs, Mode=OneWay}" />

            </StackLayout>
            <ContentView Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ContentViewTappableLabelInDrawer}" extensions:GestureExtensions.TapCommand="{Binding Path=GotoHomeCommand}">
                <controls:EnhancedLabel Style="{StaticResource LabelDrawerListHeader}" Text="HAUPTMENÜ"  />
            </ContentView>
        </Grid>
```

#### Code declaration of EnhancedLabel:

```
public class EnhancedSwitch : TemplatedView
{
    #region IsToggled

    public static BindableProperty IsToggledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsToggled), typeof(bool), typeof(EnhancedSwitch), default(bool), defaultBindingMode:BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public bool IsToggled
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsToggledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion IsToggled

    #region Text

    public static BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(EnhancedSwitch), default(string));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion Text

    #region SwitchStyle

    public static BindableProperty SwitchStyleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchStyle), typeof(Style), typeof(EnhancedSwitch), default(Style));

    public Style SwitchStyle
    {
        get { return (Style) GetValue(SwitchStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SwitchStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion SwitchStyle

    #region TextStyle

    public static BindableProperty TextStyleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextStyle), typeof(Style), typeof(EnhancedSwitch), default(Style));

    public Style TextStyle
    {
        get { return (Style) GetValue(TextStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion TextStyle

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        foreach (var child in this.GetChildren())
        {
            SetInheritedBindingContext(child, BindingContext);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnChildAdded(Element child)
    {
        base.OnChildAdded(child);
        SetInheritedBindingContext(child, BindingContext);
    }
}
```

App.xaml declaration of TemplatedView:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:EnhancedSwitch}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextStyle}"></Label>
                        <Switch Grid.Column="1" IsToggled="{TemplateBinding IsToggled}" Style="{TemplateBinding SwitchStyle}" ></Switch>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Judging from my WPF experience what i would expect is that the upper element has correct padding, but oddly enough has some ghost margin with the thickness of the padding i've assigned.

The second one shows that no padding = no margin either.

Both are declared with a margin of 0. So neither one should have any padding really.

Am i missing something or is this a bug (as it looks like to me right now)?

Bug filed [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41312):

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding/) may be of help to you.

[image: Margin and Padding in Xamarin.Forms]

Using the above image taken from that page, consider the yellow section your `SwitchCell` as a complete unit. It still contains a switch control itself, which is why having a `Padding` value set makes it look like there's a margin of sorts around it.

Comment: no. the second switch displays what 0 margin 0 padding looks like. the same issue does not happen if there is no templatedview involved

Comment: Hello Paul, didn't see you undeleted your answer. I assume you're the Paul DePietro also dealing with the filed bug ticket. If not - I think the other paul is correct about the reason of this bug. While a rendering behaviour like WPF would be optimal because it has no unexpected side effects, i've just duplicated the properties as a workaround. I hope it does get fixed at some point, before TemplatedViews are used in a broad fashion. (Judging by SO few people use new features at the time they are released)

Comment: Yes, the same. I assumed my answer may have initially been off base compared to what you were personally referring to but it does still apply to some extent, but that the padding was being double applied. I'll have to modify the explanation to clarify what was occurring when I get a chance.

Comment: i do understand what's going wrong now. I think the description you gave in bugzilla does explain the issue. However i'm hoping this behavior gets fixed, since that is not how it works in WPF. There are instances where you would want your top level ControlTemplate to have a static padding while the user defined padding should be ignored, or applied elsewhere. Just for the sake of consistency :) i would do a PR if that was an option

Comment: i suppose i've found a bug which is attempted to be solved by silence?

Comment: At the presently time we likely wouldn't immediately make a change to this behavior, as other developers' apps may be written expecting it to act in this manner. It may however be added in the future while allowing for backwards compatibility in terms of this particular behavior.

Comment: but the behaviour is plain wrong when compared to WPF and it's a feature most people probably don't even use yet (since transitioning to app.xaml is not even a thing which is in the current project template). This is rather disappointing, but i can see that it proably is not a minor change to the codebase.